# error in C++: out-of-line definition

Tags: c++

**CustomerInfo.cpp**

```
#include "CustomerInfo.h"  //  <==== Funtion Definition

CustomerInfo::CustomerInfo()  //  <==== The Scope Resolution which is two colons :: gives me access to the class
{
    newZipCode = 0;
}

CustomerInfo::CustomerInfo(string name, string address, int zipCode)
{
    newName = name;
    newAddress = address;
    newZipCode = zipCode;
}

CustomerInfo::~CustomerInfo()
{
}

string CustomerInfo::getName() const
{
    return newName;
}

string CustomerInfo::getAddress() const
{
    return newAddress;
}

int CustomerInfo::getZipCode() const
{
    return newZipCode;
}
```

**The main.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "CustomerInfo.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    string address;
    int zipCode;

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    getline (cin, name);
    cout << "Enter your address" << endl;
    getline (cin, address);
    cout << "Enter your ZipCode: ";
    cin >> zipCode;

    CustomerInfo Real_1(name, address, zipCode);

    cout << endl << " Name: " << Real_1.getName() << endl <<
        "Address:  " << Real_1.getAddress() << endl <<
        "ZipCode:  " << Real_1.getZipCode() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**The CustomerInfo.h file**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMERINFO_H
#define CUSTOMERINFO_H
// Header ==> Function Declaration
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CustomerInfo
{
 public:
    CustomerInfo(); //  <====  Default Constructor

    CustomerInfo(string, int); //  <==== Overload Constructor

   ~CustomerInfo();   //  <===== Destructor - Done using an object it will be destroyed out of memory'

    string getName() const;   //   <==== Accessor Functions - Return member variables one value at a time. In addition, no void function will be used.
    // getName - returns name of person
    string getAddress() const;
    // getAddress - returns address of person
    int getZipCode() const;
    // getZipCode - returns zipcode of person

private:
    //Member Variables
    string newName;
    string newAddress;
    int newZipCode;
};  //  <=== Requires semicolon after brackets for classes

#endif // CUSTOMERINFO_H
```

The error I receive is out-of-line definition of 'CustomerInfo' does not match any declaration in 'CustomerInfo'

The following line is the error
CustomerInfo::CustomerInfo(string name, string address, int zipCode)

Comment: You are missing your class definition, among several other things.  Have a look at [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) to see how to declare a C++ class correctly.

Comment: I am using Code Blocks for mac and have two other files main.cpp and CustomerInfo.h

Comment: Thanks Tim for responding so quickly here is my complete code for main.cpp

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow will not allow me to add further code

Comment: First of all, this question (if there is a question in it) should be asked better.  Please see [the instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  But that said... make sure the constructor in the class definition for `CustomerInfo` _in the header file_ `CustomerInfo.h` matches the signature `CustomerInfo::CustomerInfo(string, string, int)`.

Comment: I'm sorry e0k I'm new to C++ and stackoverflow.com I know it's not an excuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you define a constructor

```
CustomerInfo::CustomerInfo(string name, string address, int zipCode)
```

which does not appear in the class definition (in `CustomerInfo.h`).  The closest one is

```
CustomerInfo(string, int);
```

but it doesn't match the signature.  Just replace it with

```
CustomerInfo(string name, string address, int zipCode);
```

to your class definition in the header file.

Comment: Hi e0k, first thanks for helping me, however, I'm receiving several error messages when I just replace the code with what you just pasted above.

Comment: What are the new errors?  The basic idea is that whatever you declare in the class definition (header file) you have to define (.cpp file) with the same function signature.  Just make sure that they match.

Comment: error: reference to 'string' is ambiguous on line 34

Comment: @Juan If you have a new question it should be a new question.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a new question but new errors after replacing the one line code.

Comment: Got it e0k... I appreciate it. I needed to close Xcode and start it again. :)

Comment: Extended discussions are better done in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) than in comments.  You are new (and have <20 reputation to use the chat) and likely unfamiliar with [the custom](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments).  If you have something to add to your _original_ question, you can edit it.  But if you have a different question, then please ask a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry thanks. I have a new question which I will ask in a new post.